# Access the system library folder rather than the user library folder with Terminal

Tags: terminal

I am trying to `chmod` a folder in the library of my Mac but I can only get to the folders below the user level.

I need `Library/WebServer/Documents/...`, but I can only get to `user/me/...`, etc.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even administrator users should use `sudo -s` or `sudo chmod /Library/Webserver` since the default group structure on OS X is to protect system resources from modification without the logging the privilege escalation. You will need to be an administrator of the mac to use sudo, so you can always `su` to an existing admin account first before using sudo.